# How to use put an 'empty' value in react-hook-forms defaultValues with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hook-form

I use `react-hook-forms` with typescript and react native. When I set the `defaultValues` field in the `useForm` method I need to have in the beginning empty fields, there is no problem when the field is a string, but I have fields that for example should be a date. When I set the date to `undefined` I get a warning - `fieldname is missing in the 'defaultValue' prop of either its controller or useForm`, and when I try to set it to null I get some TypeScript error that the field in `defaultValues` must be either a Date or undefined, since `react-hook-forms` `DefaultValues` type can accept each field as an actual value or undefined.

So basically for each solution I get an error / warning. How can I solve that?

Thanks ahead.

**EDIT**:

The form data type:

```
interface FormData {
  date: Date;
}
```

But - the `DefaultValue` type for this form (this is from react-hook-form) is:

```
{
  date: Date | undefined;
}
```

**EDIT V2**:

I found a solution - in my case I used the `Controller` component `defaultValue` prop with `null` and it worked.

Comment: can you share more of your code? I think one possible solution is making that date field an optional field (with the `?`) in your Typescript interface

Comment: Hi, i put the types, when I put ```?``` it still warns the ```undefined``` warning

Comment: Hi @BaoHuynhLam, I edited the question with a solution I found, thanks anyway!

Comment: awesome. I believe another way is to use `date?: Date` in your FormData interface

Comment: That's actually what I tried at first, the problem is that in Typescript the ```undefined``` is ok but the warning is from the react-hook-form logic and not from Typescript - so even if I do that I will still get the warning